# How to unschedule a cron job in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, cron

So I have this cron code in flutter which add 10000 to the num every minute, but idk how to unschedule this.

```
main() {
var num = 0;
final cron = Cron();
cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('* * * * *'), () async {
num += 10000;
});
}
```

Do you have any idea how to unschedule/delete/cancel the scheduled task?

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: im using 'package:cron/cron.dart';

Comment: It looks like [the `schedule` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cron/latest/cron/Cron/schedule.html) returns [a `ScheduledTask` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cron/latest/cron/ScheduledTask-class.html) that provides a `cancel` method.

Comment: thank you, I just found out that a `Cron` object has close() method to stop doing the task

Comment: The documentation for [`close`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cron/latest/cron/Cron/close.html) indicates that it won't accept *new* tasks.  It does not indicate that it does anything about existing tasks.